# Limits w/ Greatest Integer and Abs. Value Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, limits, functions

Find the $$\lim _{x\to 2^+}\ {\lfloor x \rfloor - 1\over\lfloor x \rfloor - |x|}$$

Comment: @addy2012 Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \in (2,3), \  [x] = 2$

Therefore for $x \in (2,3), \ f(x) = \dfrac{2-1}{2-|x|} = \dfrac{1}{2-x}$

Now, in $(2,3)$, x is greater than $2$. So $2-x$ will be ever so slightly less than $0$ as $x \rightarrow 2^+$.

$1$ divided by very small negative number tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Are you sure about *positive ?*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No negative! edited. What a fool i am. Thank you!!

Comment: If I was given a dime for any of this kind, I should be a billionaire ! You are not a fool ! The proof $+1$. Cheers.